# What's the synonym of "Module"?

Tags: nouns, synonyms, vocabulary, linguistics

I want to know the synonym of the word "module" in the context of university.
What is another way to call a module of a university course? can I call it a subject ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can call it a subject, but perhaps a "unit".

Answer (score 2):

I believe the word **course** is frequently used for a module one completes at university, such as "Greek Linguistics I".

Comment: "Course" is an appropriate synonym for the entire thing, but in my experience, "module" more often refers to a smaller grouping of related topics that are covered during a course. And I think that's consistent with the question, where they say "a module *of* a university course". For example, an introductory linguistics course might have "modules" on Phonetics, Phonology, Morphology, Semantics, etc. This is more akin to what soysoymilk's answer proposes: "unit". "Topic" would also work, or any of a plethora of other synonyms.

Comment: @CodyGray: I have seen it used interchangeably with *course*. But you may have a point with respect to the Question's intent, considering the phrasing *module of a university course*.

Answer (score 1):

**Different universities will have different internal vocabulary**, so you should not assume there is any option that will be unambiguous. In fact, from reading your question I'm not actually sure what you are referring to by 'module of a university course'.

Suitable words might be **course**, **paper**, **chapter**, **section**, **part**, **element**, **component**, **unit** or others.

If the detail is important, either check what the specific university term is, or provide some context, for example *I studied Maths and Philosophy; the first year involved three philosophy ***courses***, each of which had eight sections* or *This semester the Medicine students are studying their Anatomy ***module***, which has three ***papers****.